# Kotlin Android, Spinner setSelection not resolved

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing :

```
mySpinner.setSelection(myObj?.spinIdx)
```

with :

```
var spinIdx: Int = 0
```

And the compiler complain about "none of the following function can be called" with
setSelection(Int) in the propositions. Why?

```
mySpinner.setSelection(myObj?.spinIdx as Int)
```

works around the problem but I don't understand the compiler here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myObj?.spinIdx` returns `null` when `myObj` is null. Read about "Safe Calls" [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html). Compilation fails because `setSelection` method accepts only `Int` which can't be `null`.

How to fix:

1. If `myObj` can be `null`:

   `if (myObj != null) {
     mySpinner.setSelection(myObj.spinIdx)
   }`
2. If `myObj` can't be `null`:

   `mySpinner.setSelection(myObj.spinIdx)`

Comment: Or maybe `mySpinner.setSelection(myObj?.spinIdx ?: 0)` or `mySpinner.setSelection(myObj!!.spinIdx)` if throwing an NPE is acceptable. AFAIK the latter is equivalent to the case `as Int`.